# XMLHttpRequest prototype override not getting called

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension to monitor the XHR response for a particular web site and log messages to the console based on the content of the response. So far I am just trying to get to the response but have not been successful yet.

Here is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "XHR Listener",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Listening in on XHR responses",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Listen!"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Here is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

And here is my `inject.js` file:

```
console.log('In inject.js');
(function() {
    console.log('In the function()');
    const dummySend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
        console.log('inside send()');
        const _onreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;

        this.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log('inside onreadystatechange()');
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                console.log(this.response);
            }
        }
        if (_onreadystatechange) {
            _onreadystatechange.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    dummySend.apply(this, arguments);
})();
```

When I click on the extension icon I get the "In inject.js" and "In the function()" messages in the console, but the other messages ("Inside send()" and "Inside onreadystatechange()") never get logged to the console even though there are multiple HMLHttpRequest actions showing up in the network tab of developer tools. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to go one level deeper and [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)